# Security header is not valid in PayPal Mass Payments

Tags: javascript, meteor, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using mateodelnorte/node-paypal-masspayments in meteor. I a mfollowing the guide in their github page. I am using the sandbox account automatically created in developers.paypal.com.

I set also the environment using

```
process.env.PAYPAL_ENV = 'sandbox'
```

But I keep receive an error of 100002, Security header is not valid.

How can I fix this? This part is to create a mass payments to emailaddresses listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the security header error will occur when there is an issue with the API credentials. Please double check the API username, password, signature, API endpoint.

You will need to use sandbox API credentials (API username, password, signature ) against sandbox API endpoint.